# Update datagrid data in another page's form in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and now I am testing simple methods. I want to edit datagrid   in form of another page. Here is my code

```
    using System;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using System.Linq;  
    using System.Web;  
    using System.Web.UI;  
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
    using System.Web.Configuration;  
    using System.Data;  
    using System.Data.SqlClient;  

    public partial class mymembertype : System.Web.UI.Page
    {  
    public static int mem_typeid;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["valueid"] != null)
        {
            mem_typeid = (int)(Session["valueid"]);
            string memtype_name = Convert.ToString(Session["valueName"]);
            string rate = Convert.ToString(Session["rate"]);
            txtmembtype.Text = Convert.ToString(memtype_name);
            txtdscrate.Text = rate;
        }
        }

    protected void Insert_membertype_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        funtions fun = new funtions();
        if (mem_typeid == null)
        {

            if (txtmembtype.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtdscrate.Text != "")
                {
                    string membetype = txtmembtype.Text;
                    int dscrate = Convert.ToInt32(txtdscrate.Text);

                    bool chk = fun.Insert_membertype(membetype, dscrate);
                    if (chk)
                        lblInfo.Text = " saving membertype successful";
                    else
                        lblInfo.Text = "Error saving membertype";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (txtmembtype.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtdscrate.Text != "")
                {
                    string membetype = txtmembtype.Text;
                    int dscrate = Convert.ToInt32(txtdscrate.Text);

                    bool chk = fun.Update_memberType(mem_typeid, membetype, dscrate);
                    if (chk)
                        lblInfo.Text = " Updating membertype successful";
                    else
                        lblInfo.Text = "Error Updating membertype";
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

here is my update function

```
    public bool Update_memberType(int id, string name, int dsc)
        {
        string connectionString =
            WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Spa"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        int memid = id;
        string membtype = name;
        int dsrate = dsc;
        Boolean chk = false;

        try
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_Membtype", myConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_typeId", memid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membertype_name", membtype);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dsc_rate", dsrate);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            chk = true;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            chk = false;
        }
        return chk;

    }
```

When I try to update data , it doesn't change nothing. Variable has its original values. Does not change to new data in text boxes. How can I fix these error.Please...

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also you should close your connection in finally block.

Comment: I got update successful message but data are not updated. When I debug the code variables are assigned with old values. I think this is problem.